# How effective is g++/gcc at unrolling recursive inline functions?

Tags: gcc, recursion, profiling, g++, stack-trace

I've recursive but not tail recursive inline function for which I'd want gcc to unroll the recursion.  Yes, I'm using `g++ -O3 -funroll-loops` of course.

```
inline void recurse_fun(..., unsigned depth = 0, unsigned max_depth = 40) {
    if (++depth > max_depth) return;
    for (auto i = ..., iend = ...; i != iend; i++) {
        if (...) continue;
        ...
        recurse_fun(...,depth,max_depth);
    }
}
```

I could easily replace this by handling a `stack<...>` object manually, which gcc should unroll properly, but it would not be as quite as elegant or maintainable.

I should really try profiling both versions regardless, but I'm curious if anyone can say with confidence that some recent gcc version would or would not handle this correctly.

Comment: Related: http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/will-it-optimize.html

Comment: Can you just look at the generated assembly language? Besides, 1) any function that does this much will see insignificant benefit from being inlined, and 2) does the compiler inline recursive functions? That would surprise me. 3) If you mean unrolling the inner loop, that won't save much either, if there's a function call inside it.

Comment: Nice find, Josh Lee!  :)  Yes, I suppose it much easier to read the assembler rather than play with the profiler, Mike Dunlavey.

Answer (score 2):

GCC (at least recent versions like 4.5 or 4.6) does unroll some tail recursive calls.
Of course you need to ask it to optimize (so `-O2` or `-O3` is required).

To understand what it is doing you can

- Ask for the assembly output with something like `gcc -O3 -fverbose-asm -S yoursource.c`
- Ask for various [dump files](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Debugging-Options.html), like `gcc -c -fdump-tree-all -fdump-ipa-all -O3 yoursource.c` (and there are other dump files)

Beware that GCC would print a lot (hundreds!) of dump files. And the dump files are only to help GCC developers or GCC plugin developers (or [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) developpers). Don't expect them to stay in the same format from one release of GCC to the next.

The numbering of the dump files is useless: it is not chronological or logical.

And the dump options are likely to change in next GCC release (*4.7*, probably in 2012)